# How to call a protocol's default function declared in a protocol extension?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm trying to call a protocol's default function that was declared in an extension:

```
protocol Tester {
    func printTest()
    }

extension Tester {
    func printTest() {
        print("XXXXTestXXXX")
    }
}

class TestController: UIViewController, Tester {

 let testing = Tester()// error here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testing.printTest()
    }

}
```

The error ''Tester' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers' keeps appearing when I try to create an instance of the protocol. Whats the best way to use default functions in protocols?

Comment: Your view controller is a `Tester`, just call `self.printTest()`

Comment: And one more thing protocol are abstractions you cannot initialize them unless, you can only initialize concrete implementation of a protocol.

Comment: Oh, good to know, was wondering why it was complaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the implementer, in your case it's `TestController` so :

`self.printTest()` will work

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol Proto { 
    // func testPrint() <- comment this out or remove it
}

extension Proto {
    func testPrint() {
        print("This extension called")
    }
}

struct Bar: Proto {
    func testPrint() {
        print("Call from Structure")
        (self as Foo).testPrint() 
    }
}

Bar().testPrint()

// Output:   'Call from Structure',
//            'This extension call'
```

Comment: this generating the following error
// Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed7bdff8)

Answer (score 0):

Protocols cannot be instantiated - ever - lets think of them Contracts

Classes CAN supposed to confrom to 1..n protocols.

---

The fact that your protocol provides a default implementation, just enables a class that conforms to it to inherit this default functionality if it doesnt need to provide a custom implementation.

a very cheap way in your case would be:

```
let testing = self
```

since your TestController class already conforms to Tester.
(Note I create a retain cycle)

===

another way would be to not use testing but `self.printTest()` 
(This might be what you want)

- Id reread the apple swift book and check out protocols (what they are and how they work)

Comment: One correction: classes do not have to conform to any protocols